# Sending a click to an img on a web page in python without Selenium

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am writing a crawler for macys.com.  I need to enter each color of each product as a seperate entry.  Their website is set up so that a script is activated when a click is sent to a swatch image that switches out the product image.  As far as I can tell, this is the only way to retrieve the product image URL (as it is not stored anywhere on the page until the swatch is clicked).  I am currently using requests and BeautifulSoup to parse the html.  This code is to be run in an environment where it would be unfeasible to install a browser (i.e I cannot use Selenium).  The swatches are not in a form tag and are not considered clickable by mechanize (or twill).

tl;dr:  How do I send a click to a non-form, non-link element found by id and tag without using Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is not exactly what you're asking for but, it certainly works. Selenium can be used without an actual browser by setting it up with a virtual display. It does require [xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) and pyvirtualdisplay (which is a wrapper for xvfb). Here's how I got it working (on ubuntu 12.04 after installing xvfb).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://www1.macys.com/shop/product/alfani-black-sweater-horizontal-texture-stripe-full-zip-sweater?ID=720780&CategoryID=4286&LinkType=PDPZ1'
browser.get(url)
el = browser.execute_script('return MACYS.pdp.primaryImages')

print el
{u'720780': {u'Blue Indigo': u'2/optimized/1291562_fpx.tif',
     u'Deep Black': u'3/optimized/1291563_fpx.tif',
     u'Flint Heather': u'4/optimized/1291564_fpx.tif',
     u'Grey Heather': u'1/optimized/1291911_fpx.tif',
     u'River Blue': u'0/optimized/1291560_fpx.tif'}}
```

It just so happens that they have a javascript namespace called `MACYS` where they keep all the info about the images (which is what I printed out there). Hope that helps.